# Measure theory - lebesgue's density theorem and changing order of limit

Tags: real-analysis, limits, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

First of all I'll say that I did see many questions in this site that try to answer a similar question like mine, but I didn't find them usefull enough.

As a part of a proof of mine I would like to claim:

$$\lim_{r\rightarrow 0^+} \frac{m(\bigcup_{i\in\mathbb N}E_i\bigcap(x-r,x+r))}{2r}\leq \sum_{i\in\mathbb N}\lim_{r\rightarrow 0^+}\frac{m(E_i\bigcap(x-r,x+r))}{2r}$$

($x\in\mathbb R$, $m$ is lebesgue measure, $r>0$, $E_i\subset \mathbb R$).
Assume That each RHS limit exists.

Comment: Why can't you just apply Lebesgue's density theorem to get the "more precise" result (left side zero outside $\bigcup E_i$ except for a null set $C$) without even looking at the right side?

Comment: What would it mean for something to be a Lebesgue point of the complement of the set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about trying $x=0$ and $E_i = (2^{-i-1},2^{-i}]$.

Comment: I see, what if I added that each RHS limit equals 0?

Comment: And btw, why is it even a counterexample?

Comment: @Functional_Analysis: It is a counterexample because the rhs is equal to $0$, but the lhs is not.